# Monitor.Wait - while or if?

Tags: c#, multithreading, monitor

Currently, I'm learning for a multithreading exam. I read [the good threading article of albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx). I've got a question at the monitor usage - why is here used a loop in place of an if?

```
lock (_locker)
{
  while (!_go) //why while and not if?
    Monitor.Wait (_locker);  // _lock is released
  // lock is regained
  ...
}
```

I think, that an if would be sufficient.

I'm afraid, that I don't understand the article completely.

//Edit
Example-Code:

```
class SimpleWaitPulse
{
  static readonly object _locker = new object();
  static bool _go;

  static void Main()
  {                                // The new thread will block
    new Thread (Work).Start();     // because _go==false.

    Console.ReadLine();            // Wait for user to hit Enter

    lock (_locker)                 // Let's now wake up the thread by
    {                              // setting _go=true and pulsing.
      _go = true;
      Monitor.Pulse (_locker);
    }
  }

  static void Work()
  {
    lock (_locker)
      while (!_go)
        Monitor.Wait (_locker);    // Lock is released while we’re waiting

    Console.WriteLine ("Woken!!!");
  }
}
```

Comment: "If" only checks once. The "while" loop will keep checking. If doesn't wait. While waits.

Comment: Hi DOK - thanks for your explanation. But I think, the Monitor.Wait Operation would be executed only once. It will be waiting for the Pulse signal. So I see no reasons for a while :-(

Comment: It depends on the remainder of the program, like what exactly is `_go` supposed to mean, and when do you set it.

Comment: Hi svick - thanks for your answer. I've added the example.

Comment: pro, it really depends how many times you want to wait for the event to occur. Normally, there is some type of modification in memory after lock and if you only want to "observe" that modification once, then you can use an if (e.g. you send a message and you wait for a single response). If you want to continuously "observe" the modifications, then do it in a while loop (i.e. you're monitoring a message stream for a large number of messages).

Comment: Pro, given the update, it seems that the best thing to do is use the while loop because you will always execute the work after the input is taken. Using an if-statement will result in a single execution of the work and any input following that will be ignored (i.e. no work will be done).

Comment: Hi Lirik, what I don't understand is, that if the thread comes to the wait method. I will be waiting until another thread will execute the pulse method. So I asume that (in every case) no more iterations needed.

Comment: Have you tried both and stepped through the code in the debugger to see the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just depends on the situation. In this case the code is just waiting for `_go` to be **true**.

Every time `_locker` is pulsed it will check to see if `_go` has been set to **true**. If `_go` is still **false**, it will wait for the next pulse.

If an *if* was used instead of a *while*, it would only wait once (or not at all if `_go` was already **true**), and would then continue on after a pulse, regardless of the new state of `_go`.

So how you use Monitor.Wait() depends entirely on your specific needs.

Answer (score 3):

It really just depends on the situation. But first, we need to clarify how Monitors work. When a thread proceeds to signal a thread through Monitor.Pulse(), there is usually no guarantee that the signaled thread will actually run next. This means that it is possible for other threads to run before the signaled thread and change the condition under which it was okay for the signaled thread to proceed. This means that the signaled thread still needs to check if is safe for it to proceed after being woken up (ie the while loop). However, certain rare synchronization problems allow you to make the assumption that once a thread has been signaled to wake up (ie Monitor.Pulse()), no other thread has the ability to change the condition under which it is safe to proceed (ie. the if condition).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an article that might help here: [Wait and Pulse demystified](http://nickbutler.net/Article/WaitPulse)

There's more going on than is immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1):

> I've got a question at the monitor usage - why is here used a loop in
>   place of an if?

There is a well known rule when working with `Pulse` and `Wait` that states that when in doubt prefer `while` over an `if`. Clearly, either one will work in this case, but in almost every other situation `while` is required. In fact, there are very few (if any) scenarios where using a `while` loop would produce an incorrect result. That is the basis for this general rule. The author used a `while` loop because he was trying to stick with the tried-and-true pattern. He even provides the template in the same article. Here is it is:

```
lock (_locker)
  while ( <blocking-condition> )
    Monitor.Wait (_locker);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to write correct code with `Monitor.Wait` is to assume the system will regard it as "advisory", and assume that the system may arbitrarily wake any waiting thread any time it can acquire the lock, without regard for whether `Pulse` has been called.  The system usually *won't* do so, of course, but if a program is using `Wait` and `Pulse` properly, its correctness should not be affected by having `Wait` calls arbitrarily exit early for no reason.  Essentially, one should regard `Wait` as a means of telling the system "Continuing execution past here will be a waste of time unless or until someone else calls `Pulse`".